# "Oops! Something bad has happened" Error when entering Stack Overflow chat

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat

I get the "Oops! Something bad has happened" error when entering Stack Overflow chat. What might cause this?

I have been having this issue for 6 months now.

As per the tests run with Bart, I can come into chat here on Meta Stack Exchange. I entered the Tavern, and he saw me appear.

However, when going to a specific Stack Overflow chat room, it tells me I need to log in to be able to chat. When I do so, I get the problems mentioned above.

Answer (score 15):

You're having trouble logging into chat on Stack Overflow because a moderator deleted your previous account and destroyed your chat profile. They did this because it is pretty clear that this is a sock puppet account of [this suspended user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3602281/don-larynx), who posted a series of pretty disgusting slurs against multiple members of the site, and has done this on multiple occasions.

It seems clear to us that you were simply hoping to gain access to chat to insult people once again, so we've fixed the problem by destroying your Stack Overflow account. You are no longer welcome to participate on this site, in any form.